# Compiled python version: ModuleNotFoundError at import

Tags: python, linux, conda

I have a project in a `conda` environment that runs with python 3.7.7 (on linux). When I recompile the same version of python (3.7.7) and put/replace the executable at the same location, I expect the program to run the same way, but the import fails.

With the original version of python:

```
(condaenv) mypc:~/Proj$ /home/me/.conda/envs/condaenv/bin/python3.7.bak
Python 3.7.7 (default, Mar 26 2020, 15:48:22) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import gym
>>> quit()
```

With the compiled version:

```
(condaenv) mypc:~/Proj$ /home/me/.conda/condaenv/proj/bin/python3.7
Python 3.7.7 (default, Sep 24 2020, 16:28:06) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import gym
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gym'
>>> quit()
```

The environment variables are supposed to be the same as I run from the same location, on the same terminal, without altering it between the two calls. Since the first import works without any problem, the packages are well installed.

The system imports such as `sys` work fine in both version, but I had to export `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` before for the compiled version, which was not the case for the "normal" version. But keeping the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` unchanged between the two calls don't change anything.

What happens that the second call can't find the matching package? What am I missing?

-- **Edit 1** --

The compiled version shared objects dependencies are the following:

```
$ ldd python3.7
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffed457a000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f63e53a6000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f63e53a0000)
        libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f63e539b000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f63e524c000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f63e505a000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f63e577f000)
```

The original python are the following:

```
$ ldd python3.7.bak 
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc0d1c8000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f89ab6bc000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f89ab4ca000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f89ab4c4000)
        libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f89ab4bf000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f89ab4b4000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f89ab365000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f89aba80000)
```

The versions differs a bit because they are not compiled with the same version of the compiler (I guess). I am however surprised that the new version doesn't require `librt.so` but the original version does. It could be because of the compilation flags though, which prevent the optimisation. I added `--without-pymalloc --with-pydebug --with-valgrind` during the configure step. But I don't think it should interfere with python normal behaviour with library.

Comment: Perhaps comparing the output of checking `ldd` on the two Python binaries would helpful. E.g., `ldd /home/me/.conda/condaenv/proj/bin/python3.7` vs `ldd /home/me/.conda/condaenv/proj/bin/python3.7.bak`. Feel free to add those outputs to the question.

Comment: @merv Thank you for your insight! I modified the question. Nothing comes out of the ordinary to me, but maybe you'll notice something out of it?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not seeing much either. I think your idea about compilation flags could be fruitful. Maybe worth checking out the feedstock for Python on GitHub to see exactly how the compilation is done for the Conda builds (e.g., Anaconda or Conda Forge). Otherwise not sure where else to look.

Comment: Perhaps too obvious, but what is `sys.path` in each case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `--without-pymalloc` and `--with-pydebug` flags to `./configure` are likely causing the error. Replacing the `python3.7` binary in miniconda with one built with `./configure --without-pymalloc` or `./configure --with-pydebug` prevents the import of compiled libraries, like `math` and `numpy`. Compiling without any flags (i.e., `./configure && make`) does not cause these errors. Compiling with `./configure --with-valgrind` also does not raise errors when importing compiled libraries.

---

Older answer:

Can you please try with the [configure flags used by conda-forge](https://github.com/conda-forge/python-feedstock/blob/89372387ea6cc5aafc554a44028fa2faad5cb5d8/recipe/build_base.sh#L229-L239)? Using these flags, I was able to replace the `python3.7` binary in a conda environment, and imports continued to work. If I used the OP's flags (i.e., `--without-pymalloc --with-pydebug --with-valgrind`), then importing compiled libraries did not work (e.g., math, numpy).

```
curl -L https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.7/Python-3.7.7.tar.xz | tar xJ
cd Python-3.7.7
./configure \
    --prefix=/tmp/python3.7 \
    --enable-ipv6 \
    --with-ensurepip=no \
    --with-computed-gotos \
    --with-system-ffi \
    --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions \
    --with-lto \
    --enable-optimizations \
    --with-valgrind
make -j
```

The solution involves one of these flags -- perhaps `--with-lto` or `--enable-optimizations`.

Comment: Confirmed, that is the problem. I find it however odd that python readme ask to compiles with the `--without-pymalloc --with-pydebug --with-valgrind` flags when it is designed to be used with valgrind, but it doesn't work in practive with numpy...

Comment: Python/pip seem to "know" that the numpy wheel is incompatible with python built with `./configure --without-pymalloc --with-pydebug --with-valgrind`. If you install numpy with the manually-built python, then it builds numpy from source instead of downloading the compiled wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you compiled the new Python? It could be that missing lib `librt.so.1` is the culprit for the error message. Is there any chance to install the `librt` package (depends on your Linux flavor) and recompile Python.

Comment: Well, ldd gives the dependencies. Not having `librt` as a dependency on the compiled version means that python won't even look at `librt`(afaik). So reinstalling it shouldn't change anything or maybe break the working version that does depend on it.